# Evaluate expression tree in Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, expression-trees

I have input consisting of nested logical expression objects

Ex:

```
var obj = {
  'OR': [
      {
        'AND': [
            false, true, true
        ]
      },
      {
        'OR': [
            true, false, false, {
                'AND': [true, true]
            }
        ]
      },
      true
  ]
};
```

Which is equivalent to `((false && true && true) || (true || false || false || (true && true)) || true)`

We need to write a function that calculates this

Approach:

Go to the innermost level and evaluate it first, moving to the top

```
var expressionEvaluator = function(opArr){
            var hasChildObjects = function(arr){
                if(Array.isArray(arr)){
                    return arr.some(function(obj){
                        return typeof(obj) === 'object';
                    });
                }
                else if(typeof(arr) === 'object'){
                    return true;
                }
            };
            var evaluateArr = function(list, operator){
                var result;
                if(operator === 'AND'){
                    result = true;
                    for(var i = 0; i<list.length; i++){
                        if(!list[i]){
                            result = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if(operator === 'OR'){
                    result = false;
                    for(var i = 0; i<list.length; i++){
                        if(list[i]){
                            result = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return result;
            };
            var iterate = function(opArr){
                Object.keys(opArr).forEach(function(k){
                    if(hasChildObjects(opArr[k])){
                        iterate(opArr[k]);
                    }
                    else{
                        opArr = evaluateArr(opArr[k], k);
                    }
                });
            };
            iterate(opArr);
            return result;
        }
```

I am able to reach the innermost object and evaluate it but not reach back to the topmost level and evaluate the entire expression object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a simple recursive function.

- If the current object has `OR` key, then check if [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) of the items in the array are `truthy`.
- If `AND`, check if [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) item is `truthy`.
- If one of the item in the array is an object, recursively call the function on the object to get its *value*

```js
const input={OR:[{AND:[false,true,true]},{OR:[true,false,false,{AND:[true,true]}]},true]};

function evaluate({ OR, AND }) {
  if (OR)
    return OR.some(c => typeof c === 'object' ? evaluate(c) : c)
  if (AND)
    return AND.every(c => typeof c === 'object' ? evaluate(c) : c)
}

console.log(evaluate(input))
```

Since the callback functions are same, you could also get the operation to a variable and call it dynamically:

```js
function evaluate({ OR, AND }) {
  const array = OR ?? AND,
        operation = OR ? 'some' : 'every';
  
  return array[operation](c => typeof c === 'object' ? evaluate(c) : c)
}
```

OR

```js
const evaluate = ({ OR, AND }) => OR ? OR.some(callback) : AND.every(callback),
      callback = c => typeof c === 'object' ? evaluate(c) : c
```

Comment: Could even just `(OR ?? AND)[OR ? 'some' : 'every'](...)`, though I realize this isn't code golf

Comment: @adiga Can we also add a null / undefined check for any of the keys, array values?

Comment: @user544079 try replacing `typeof c === 'object'` with `Object(c) === c`

Answer (score 4):

Another variant on the theme here:

```js
const evaluate = (tree) =>
  typeof tree === 'boolean'
    ? tree
  : 'OR' in tree
    ? tree .OR .some (evaluate)
  : 'AND' in tree
    ? tree .AND .every (evaluate)
  : false // or throw an error?

const tree = {OR: [{AND: [false, true, true]}, {OR: [true, false, false, {AND: [true, true]}]}, true]}

console .log (evaluate (tree))
```

`evaluate` returns the value supplied if it's a boolean.  Otherwise it checks for `'OR'` or `'AND'` nodes, and handles them appropriately.  There is a catch-all at the end for non-well-formed trees.  Here I return `false`, but you might throw an error, return `null`, or something else.

If you don't need that catch-all, this can be simplified to a one-liner:

```js
const evaluate = (tree) =>
  typeof tree == 'boolean' ? tree: tree.OR ? tree.OR .some (evaluate) : tree.AND .every (evaluate)
```

---

But I'm concerned by the tree structure.  I always worry when there are objects that can only have one property.  It feels like an array is then a better design.

This alternative feels cleaner:

```js
const tree = [
  'OR', 
  [
    ['AND', [false, true, true]], 
    ['OR', [true, false, false, ['AND', [true, true]]]], 
    true
  ]
]
```

And that could be evaluated with similar code:

```js
const evaluate = (tree) =>
  typeof tree == 'boolean' ? tree : tree [1] [tree [0] === 'OR' ? 'some' : 'every'] (evaluate)
```

**Update**: [A comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65211902#comment115299779_65218570) from customcommander pointed out that even this array format is overcomplicated.

If instead, we were dealing with something like this:

```js
const tree = [
  'OR', 
  ['AND', false, true, true], 
  ['OR', true, false, false, ['AND', true, true]], 
  true
]
```

then we could use a version like this:

```js
const evaluate = (tree) =>
  typeof tree === 'boolean' 
    ? tree 
    : tree .slice (1) [tree [0] === 'OR' ? 'some' : 'every'] (evaluate)
```

Comment: +1 For suggesting a different data structure. Perhaps it could be streamlined down a bit further: `[OR, true, [AND, true, false]]`?

Comment: @customcommander: yes, I think that would be better.

Comment: @customcommander: Added one more version with that format.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is a good solution but I thought we could be a bit "lazy" and avoid unnecessary recursion which may or may not help depending on the size of your expression tree.

In the following expression there is no need to evaluate both *A* & *B* since *C* is already true:

```js
{OR: [{/* ... */}, {/* ... */}, true]}
//    ^            ^            ^
//    A            B            C
```

Similarly there is no need to evaluate both *A* & *B* since *C* is already false:

```js
{AND: [{/* ... */}, {/* ... */}, false]}
//     ^            ^            ^
//     A            B            C
```

With that in mind I came up with the following code:

```js
const lazy_or = exp => exp.find(e => e === true);
const lazy_and = exp => exp.find(e => e === false);

const evaluate =
  exp =>
      typeof exp === "boolean"                ? exp
    : exp.OR && lazy_or(exp.OR)               ? true
    : exp.OR                                  ? exp.OR.some(evaluate)
    : exp.AND && lazy_and(exp.AND) === false  ? false
                                              : exp.AND.every(evaluate);
```

Comment: My concern with that notion of optimization is that we could short-circuit much faster at times if we checked earlier ones right away:  `{OR: [false, {AND: [true, true]}, false, false, false, ... (a million times)... false]}`.  Without knowing the balance of booleans and objects, it seems to be just guessing.

Comment: @ScottSauyet That's fair. I don't think my answer is a particularly good one but I thought it'd be useful to mention it (no one else did and perhaps for a good reason). But the same argument could be made for `{OR: [false, {OR: [ false, {OR: [ false, { ...(deeply nested) ... }]}]}, true]}`. You are right though that this would be just guessing and hoping for the best.

Comment: Yes, that's all I meant.  This sort of optimization is useful only if one knows much more about the data.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function evalOBJ(obj) {
    let result = true;
    if (obj.OR) {
        result = false;
        for (const v of obj.OR) {
            if (typeof v === 'object') {
                result = result || evalOBJ(v);
            } else {
                result = result || v;
            }
        }
    } else if (obj.AND) {
        for (const v of obj.AND) {
            if (typeof v === 'object') {
                result = result && evalOBJ(v);
            } else {
                result = result && v;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is fundamentally the same operation as [adiga's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65212221/) but variation uses mutual recursion between `evaluate` and the operator functions. The main benefit is separation between the algorithm traversing the tree `evaluate` and the actual operators used. It's easier to refactor to handle other operations if needed, by just adding them to `operators`.

```js
const operators = {
  "OR" : arr => arr.some(evaluate),
  "AND": arr => arr.every(evaluate),
}

function evaluate(input) {
  if (typeof input !== "object") 
    return input;
  
  const [op, value] = Object.entries(input)[0];
  return operators[op](value);
}

test(true);
test(false);
test({"OR": [false, true]});
test({"OR": [false, false]});

test({"AND": [true, true]});
test({"AND": [false, true]});

test({
  'OR': [
      {
        'AND': [
            false, true, true
        ]
      },
      {
        'OR': [
            true, false, false, {
                'AND': [true, true]
            }
        ]
      },
      true
  ]
})

function test(input) {
  console.log(`evaluating: ${JSON.stringify(input, undefined, 2)}
  result: ${evaluate(input)}`)
}
```

To showcase the ease of extension, we can convert this to also handle mathematical operations by just adding operators that handle addition and multiplication:

```js
const operators = {
  "OR" : arr => arr.some(evaluate),
  "AND": arr => arr.every(evaluate),
  "+": arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + evaluate(b), 0),
  "*": arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => a * evaluate(b), 1),
}

function evaluate(input) {
  if (typeof input !== "object") 
    return input;
  
  const [op, value] = Object.entries(input)[0];
  return operators[op](value);
}

test({"+": [2, 3]});
test({"*": [2, 3]});
test({
  '+': [
      {
        '*': [
            2, 2, 5
        ]
      },
      {
        '+': [
            6, 4, 3, {
                '*': [1, 7]
            }
        ]
      },
      2
  ]
})

function test(input) {
  console.log(`evaluating: ${JSON.stringify(input, undefined, 2)}
  result: ${evaluate(input)}`)
}
```