# Recursive method to calculate the Boolean value of an array

Tags: php, json, laravel, recursion

I'm working on a Laravel/php app and I have this array where I want to collect the final result:

```
[
    {
        "nodeType": "or",
        "0": {
            "nodeType": "and",
            "0": {
                "nodeType": "and",
                "1": true,
                "2": false
            },
            "3": true
        },
        "2": {
            "nodeType": "or",
            "4": false,
            "5": true
        }
    }
]
```

I would like to be able to collect the final value which is either True or False. The array itself could contain any number of children, for example:

```
[
    {
        "nodeType": "or",
        "0": {
            "nodeType": "and",
            "0": {
                "nodeType": "or",
                "0": {
                    "nodeType": "and",
                    "1": true,
                    "2": false
                },
                "3": true
            },
            "3": true
        },
        "2": {
            "nodeType": "or",
            "4": false,
            "5": true
        }
    }
]
```

What would be the best way to go around this? I think loops don't work since the depth of the array is not fixed.

**Edit 1**:
to answer some of the questions in the comments. The keys have no importance. the nodes has always two values. But a value could have its two values as in the second example.
The outer level is an array but this array has only one entry. So it can simply be used as `array[0]` to get to the json object.

**Edit 2**:
The result for the following array should be false but the first answer returns true.

```
{
    "nodeType": "and",
    "0": {
        "nodeType": "and",
        "0": {
            "nodeType": "and",
            "1": true,
            "2": false
        },
        "3": true
    },
    "2": {
        "nodeType": "or",
        "4": false,
        "5": true
    }
}
```

The `nodetype` can be either `and` or `or`. It is not always as written in the examples above.

Comment: Is there any significance to the keys, like "0", "2", "3"?

Comment: Here is a similar problem in JS that can serve as inspiration: [Evaluate expression tree in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65211902) the data layout is slightly different but overall it seems to be the same problem: there is an expression tree that needs to be folded down by evaluating all nodes.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that an _and_ or _or_ node always has two values, or can there be one and also more than two?

Comment: Why is the outer level of the JSON structure an array? What would happen if that array has more than one entry?

Comment: Please check the edit @trincot

Comment: Please check the edit @lukas.j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a recursive function, like this:

```
function deduct($expr) {
    if (is_bool($expr)) return $expr; // Base case
    // If OR, we can stop when we find true (and return true). 
    // If AND, we can stop when we find false (and return false).
    $search = $expr["nodeType"] == "or";
    foreach ($expr as $key => $value) {
        if ($key !== "nodeType" && deduct($value) === $search) return $search;
    }
    // If that never happened, return the opposite (false for OR, true for AND)
    return !$search;
}
```

Example call using your second JSON as input:

```
$json = '[{"nodeType": "or","0": {"nodeType": "and", "0": {"nodeType": "or", "0": {"nodeType": "and","1": true,"2": false},"3": true},"3": true},"2": {"nodeType": "or","4": false,"5": true}}]';
$obj = json_decode($json, true)[0]; // The outer level is an array: unwrap it.
var_dump(deduct($obj));
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
```

Comment: Thank you. Very close but unfortunately, it doesn't always return the correct answer. @trincot please see my second edit.

Comment: I don't get it. The "edit 2" example in your question will return `false` with my code. Is that not expected?

Comment: Unfortunately, the code is returning true instead of false.

Comment: Then you are doing something different. Here is where I see `false`: https://3v4l.org/q6Cnp#v8.1.3

Comment: I'm using it inside Laravel with php 7.4. But I used the same string but I'm getting true instead of false.

Comment: It seems php 7.4 has a different behaviour with `!=`. So it should be changed to `!==`. Updated code in my answer. Runnable here: https://3v4l.org/eAuM2#v7.4.28

Comment: Works. thank you. could you please explain this line if ($key !== "nodeType" && $this->deduct($value) === $search) ?

Comment: I think the first condition is evident? The second makes the recursive call. That recursive call will return false or true. If it is equal to `$search`, it means we have enough information to know the final outcome. For an OR we know enough when an operand evaluates to true (no matter what other operands evaluate to). For an AND we know enough when an operand evaluates to false.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71394748/php-how-to-evaluate-a-recursive-json-object-contains-true-and-false-values